# Java Secure Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, https

I am attempting to convert a http webservice to https.  I added the tags to the webservice.

```
@SecurityDomain(value = "jboss-ssl")
```

and

```
@WebContext(contextRoot="/path/one",  // already here
 urlPattern="/X",   // already here
    authMethod = "CLIENT-CERT",  // added
    transportGuarantee = "CONFIDENTIAL") // added
```

But when my client trys to connect to `https://hostname:80/path/to/ws` I get an exception:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <hostname>`.

( entire thing shown below).  I suspect that this has to do with the certificate that is being used.  I think that I need to use the java keytool to resolve this.  If someone could verify for me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callInternal(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:66)
        at com.alcatel.tpapps.common.utils.SOAPClient.execute(SOAPClient.java:146)
        at com.alcatel.tpapps.common.utils.SOAPClient.main(SOAPClient.java:233)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:192)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPRemotingConnection.invoke(SOAPRemotingConnection.java:77)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callInternal(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:106)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker. HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <hostname>.
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:368)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:148)
        at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1858)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:718)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:171)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <hostname>
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:490)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:415)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:857)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:288)
        ... 10 more
```

### Update 1

I tried the following but it had no effect on the exception:

```
hostname[username:/path/two/path][525]% keytool -genkey -keystore server.keystore -alias hostname
...
...
```

### Update 2

Actually not sure what I did in Update 1 was right because I did not have to specify a host name there...

### Update 3

I specified hostname as the Alias name

and

```
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  hostname
```

But that still did not solve my issue.  Is there a specific way to add a host name?

---

I am pretty sure that this post solves the issue however it is too cryptic to understand.  Come back to this.

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5315653

Answer (score 3):

This solution is helpful as well.

[Java's keytool command with IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168969/javas-keytool-command-with-ip-addresses)

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
        System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName + " vs. " + session.getPeerHost());
        return true;
    }
};

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

Answer (score 2):

These seem like similar issues:

### [Link 1](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=620276&messageID=3514309)

Same problem.

### [Link 2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/205423/Sockets-Internet-Protocols/java/Exception-java-io-IOException-Server)

Accepts all certificates.

```
private static final HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
      return true;
   }
};
...
HttpsUrlConnection con = (HttpsUrlConnection)new URL("https://foo.bar.com").openConnection();
con.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

However I am not certain where to put this. Client side or server side? Regardless I would rather just set up the certificates properly if that is an option.

### [Link 3](http://www.coderanch.com/t/354489/Servlets/java/IOException-Server-Certificate-SubjectDN)

Uses this solution:

```
HostnameVerifier ver = new HostnameVerifier()
{
  public boolean verify(String urlHostname,String certHostname)
  {
    return java.net.InetAddress.getByName(urlHostname).equals(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(certHostname));
  }
};
com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection con = ...(obtain connection);
con.setHostnameVerifier(ver);
```

However I am not certain where to put this.  Client side or server side?  Regardless I would rather just set up the certificates properly if that is an option.