# Install4j code signing

Tags: install4j

Install4j throws `"file.spc does not contain the complete certificate chain. Please add root and intermediate certificates."`

I have generated a certificate, it's private key and the spc file.

The certificate has been added to the *"Trusted Root Certification Authorities"* and *"Intermediate Certificate Authorities"*.
Still it gives the above error.

Please provide some help regarding this issue.

Comment: The entire certificate chain must be in the spc file, otherwise it will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654543/how-to-create-pfx-with-my-chain-of-certificates

Comment: You're using a self-signed certificate to test, right? I'm in the same situation and having the same problem. I guess i4j requires a non-zero certificate chain. I tried to generate one following one of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200176/keytool-create-a-trusted-self-signed-certificate but couldn't make it work so far.