# How to disable WSO2 BAM Thrift authentication

Tags: thrift, wso2, wso2-bam

Is it possible to disable WSO2 BAM thrift authentication?
We're publishing BAM on a different host than "localhost" and we're getting the following error

```
507672 [pool-7-thread-30] ERROR org.wso2.carbon.bam.agent.publish.ThriftAuthenti
cationClient  - Transport Exception for user : admin for url : https://XXX.YYY.ZZZ
.WWW:PORT/
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeExcep
tion: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names pres
ent
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:154)
```

We've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834673/localhost-used-as-common-name-in-the-default-wso2-certificate-creates-no-subje) that we should re-generate the truststore; but we're wondering if we can disable the authentication instead as we're just running tests for the moment.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in WSO2 BAM we can transfer data via Thrift only after initial authentication. But for the efficiency purposes we can send payload data via Thrift without authentication. But even in this case initial authentication is required for JSP pages.

For fully authenticated data use ssl://192.168.1.2:9:7611 like format and,
For not authenticating data use tcp://192.168.1.2:9:7711 like format
for connection URL.

Note that 7611 and 7711 are relevant to the Thrift server port numbers.